# What is it in my code that causes there to be an infinite error when I am training my network in Pytorch?

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch, linear-regression, loss-function

Here is my code:

[image]

I am working with a very large data set (there are several million values). My input data has 12 features, while my output data has 1 feature. This is my first time using Pytorch, so I started off with a basic linear network. When I ran it through a few epochs, I got an infinite error as you can see.

Edit (updated my code to use DataLoader):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AK1bJ.png)

As of 18 epochs, I still have nan error, and I'm not sure why.

Comment: You should batch your inputs. People tend to do this with DataLoaders, but you can simply do a for loop over your inputs using a for loop with an increment of `batch_size`. At the moment you're backpropagating what i think is your entire dataset at once, which will be extremely suboptimal. Have you also normalised/standardised your inputs? This is typically pretty important/helpful.

Comment: Post a portion of the dataset that will be helpful to see what is wrong

Comment: Hello, @jhso I used the data loader now, with a batch size of 4096. However, I am still getting the same errors.

Comment: Is the outcome/target variable binary or continuous within [0, 1] in your case? Otherwise, it would not make sense to use sigmoid activation for the model output. Btw, did you try a smaller learning rate? A over-large learning rate can cause training loss to diverge.

Comment: @TQCH oh, my target variable does not match those conditions. Thanks for that! Can I just safely remove the sigmoid part and have it work? I'll also try out a smaller learning rate. Edit: I tried it out, and the loss no longer goes to infinity. However, it now seems to have stopped at 24795.45. Is there a way to bring it lower?